# How can i return User() in Json from Django after logging in?

Tags: json, flutter

In my backend algorithm when i login it returns full user details like this:

**For Example:**

```
# If server returns 200 it also returns user info

"token": "token here",
"user": {
   "id": "id here",
   "email": "userabc@gmail.com",
   "username": "userabc",
   "first_name": null,
   "last_name": null,
   "sign_up_date": "2020-07-30T11:56:12.703000Z",
   "last_login": "2020-08-03T12:34:24.305638Z"
}
```

I have a Json function like this:

```
  Future<User> signIn(String email, String password) async {

...# Necessary function   

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       return User();
    }

    else {
    ...
    }
```

It authenticates fine,but i don't know how to return the user.How can i do it,does anybody have any idea?

Update 1:

[image]

Update 2:

1st Error : User = **list**.map((model) => U.fromJson(model)).toList();

2nd Error : User = list.map((model) => **U**.fromJson(model)).toList();

3rd Error : **User** = list.map((model) => U.fromJson(model)).toList();

Rest of the code works fine.

Update 3:

[image]

Comment: it is not firebase,it is django that i am using.@Uni

Comment: What are you getting when you are doing `return User;` @user97972?

Comment: i am redirecting user to a main page where i show their info.I get exactly what i showed in json output in first part.@Alok

Comment: If you are getting the data, and as your question says, `Returning the user data in JSON`. The response I can see is in the JSON format only @user97972 What is the problem?

Comment: @Alok my problem is that getting that data and showing it. The data i am showing is from Back-end ,i can't get it from flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You must create User model from json:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
Iterable list = map['user'];
User = list.map((model) => U.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

And before:

```
User(
        this.id,
        this.email,
        this.userName,
        this.firstName,
        this.lastName,
        this.signUpDate,
        this.lastLogin,
        );

User.fromJson(Map json)
        :   id = json['id'],
            email = json['email'],
            userName = json['username'],
            firstName = json['first_name'],
            lastName = json['last_name'],
            signUpDate = json['sign_up_date'],
            lastLogin = json['last_login'];
```

Comment: I have already declared the user model to map,but i have the following errors (Mentioned in Update 1)

Comment: They are mentioned in Update 2

Comment: @user97972

Okey, my bad - replace U to User


`users = [];
Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
Iterable list = map['user'];
users = list.map((model) => User.fromJson(model)).toList();`

Comment: thanks.Now the only problem that remains is "users" is undefined.What can i do about it?

Comment: You declared User model in the same file where used `User = list.map((model) => U.fromJson(model)).toList();` ? If no, you must import file with User model

Comment: i mean the users = []; ,not the User

Comment: i have stated my problem in Update 3.As you can see i don't have any problem with User as it is defined.